# Align dynamic component to centre of the page

Tags: html, css

I am creating a page which looks like below:

[image]

Here is my markup and code:

```
<p>list sim works</p>
<div class="app-request-view" style="background-color:  #F3F6F8; text-align: center; height: 1005; display: flex;">
<ng-container style="margin: auto;">

<card  *ngFor="let p of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]" style="margin-left: 16px; margin-top: 20px;" class="app-request-card" >
    <card-header>
        <card-header-section>
            <span class="card-header-label">Header</span>
        </card-header-section>
    </card-header>
    <main class="card-body--padding">
        Description
    </main>
    <card-footer>
        <card-footer-section [align]="'right'">
            <button [color]="'primary'" [label]="'Add'" [disabled]="'true'"></button>
        </card-footer-section>
    </card-footer>
</card>

</ng-container>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.app-request-card {
    border: none;
    max-width: 350px;
    min-width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 350px;
}
```

1. The the number of cards are populating dynamically. How to align the these these cards to the centre of the page?
2. The background color is applied only to the cards, how to set background color to complete page?

Comment: A [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) would be useful here, so html and css without the angular parts. But add flexbox to the parent container as well to center its children. More on that in the [Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

> Can use this css for cards wrapper `ng-container`. add a class to it as you want & insert this css to that class.

```
display: flex;
max-width: 1480px;
justify-content: center;
margin: 0 auto;
```